# Entity Framework ConnectionString in App Config with duplicated table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

For some reason I have a database with three types of tables with the same name but the prefix is different. The schema of database is this:

[image]

I must implement only the dbo.SpRicezioneSpedizioniLight tables manually and I have realized there are these two classes:

```
public class SpRicezioneSpedizioniLight
{
    public string AudOperation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> AudDateLog { get; set; }
    public int PROGRESSIVO { get; set; }
}

public class GemapDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLight> SpRicezioneSpedizioniLights { get; set; }
}
```

How can I identify the specific table dbo.SpRicezioneSpedizioniLight? For now my connection string is:

```
<add name="SABIntegrationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelTest.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelTest.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=SABIntegration;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

All of this works fine in a local database with a single table.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "prefix" of your tablename is the name of the schema this table is associated with. "dbo" is the default schema name used by EF.

You can change the default schema by using 
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);
in your OnModelCreating-Method or map your other type to the type explicitly using
modelBuilder.Entity().ToTable("SpRicezioneSpedizioniLight", "bak");